# Validate XML against XSD software

Tags: xml, xsd

What graphical software do you recomend to validate a XML file against XSD definition file?

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio will do this for you. So too will Altova Xml Spy.

There are also a number of free tools that can do this for you; check out DanSharp XmlViewer @ http://www.bizbert.com/bizbert/2007/11/25/DanSharp+XmlViewer.aspx

this does a great job of assisting with XPath statements and XSD validations etc.

Comment: I'm familiar with using code in VS to do validation but how do you do it in just the IDE?

Comment: @Fireworks - if your xml file references the schema properly so that VS can find it, you'll get syntax highlighting and error messages.  You can add xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///c:/temp/whatever.xsd" to the root element of your xml file to reference a schema for elements with no namespace, otherwise you can use xsi:schemaLocation="<namespace> file:///C:/temp/whatever.xsd" for namespaced elements.

Answer (score 2):

Liquid XML Studio isn't a bad option, and from what I remember it'll do what you need.:

http://www.liquid-technologies.com/

Answer (score 2):

[XML-ValidatorBuddy](http://www.xml-tools.com/download.htm)  is an affordable and easy to use tool for validation and it also works for multiple and large XML files.

Answer (score 1):

Altova XML: [Link](http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is always useful when validating against an XML Schema to be able use multiple XML Schema engines. 
This is especially useful when you have errors and one processor may describe better than the others the respective error situation. 
Also it is good to be able to use the same engine that you use in your production system also during development.

There are at least two graphical XML schema editors that support multiple XML Schema engines:

- oXygen XML Editor
- Stylus Studio

Answer (score 1):

If you have BizTalk installed, then you can do that in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

or use this  [website](http://www.xmlvalidation.com/)
First enter xml than xsd.

Answer (score 0):

Most IDEs will do this for you.  Although they are usually just a wrapper for a command line parser.

Why does it need to be graphical?